# How to find a Group owner device automatically

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am developing an android application , in which i need to connect multiple devices with each other using WiFi Direct. i am done with multiple connections as i am aware of connecting devices through one group owner device as if all client devices sends a request to one specific device.But i am doing it manually because if all client devices clicks on a name of one specific device then it is OK with multiple connections.But now i need to do it programmatically so that one device automatically becomes group owner and all other devices should automatically send connection request to that specific device.Please help me with this problem.I am stuck at this point from last many days.Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exact logic/problem there ?

Does it has to be fully automated ? or can the group owner selection be manual ?

In case all devices start the connections same time, then you must really do either manual selection, or have the devices somehow negotiate how they are selecting the group owner. Selection case you be really easy:

- Group owner uses createGroup to create the group for connection
- Group owner adds local service, and starts Peers Discovery and keeps it running (generally my research has shown that if there is no active connection, or peer discovery, the device local service is invisible for other dervices)
- Clients, simply do Peer & Service discovery and do the connections

if there is possibility that the devices appear is same place different times, then of course the logic for fully automatic would be simple.

- First all devices advertise & search for devices same time
- with The first connection one device is set as Group owner and the other gets to be client
- Both devices stop Peer & service discoveries
- The Client device stops advertising the service, thus making the Group owner only visible service for any devices appearing into the vicinity, thus they would be connecting to it.

Anyways, I would have small example project which might help you at: [Thali/WDConApp](https://github.com/thaliproject/WDConApp), anyways, with WiFi-Direct you would need to manually allow connections, You would try doing the pairing [as I explained in my Blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=46), though I have to admit that since tuesday this week, I'm not so sure if it really works that way. I would need to do some additional tests (when I have time) to verify that I would actually know how it behaves.

Then, if you don't want to have the manual user acceptance of the dialogs, I would have two options for you. You could use unsecured Bluetooth connection as is used in [Thali/BtConApp](https://github.com/thaliproject/BTConApp), or you could use WiFi Direct Access points for connectivity.

Note that Using the access point connectivity, will cut off any other WiFi connections. I do have example for it as well, and I actually uploaded it while writing this reply and you can find it from [Thali/WAPConApp](https://github.com/thaliproject/WAPConApp). Note that its just my first test version, and I'll likely do loads more work on improving it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have another question related to this topic.lets suppose 3 devices starts peer discovery at the same time.and every device finds other 2 devices .Now they should automatically connect with each other.Can you please tell me how this connection  process will work.How will every device behave during negotiation process.Actually i want to know what is this negotiation process and how i will do it programmatically.It will be a great help.

Comment: Basically its likely that the connection process will fail, thus you should build logic that starts the search & connection process again. I also added additional random time in Service discovery phase, which should mean that the connection attempts right after a failed one, should not be going on exactly same time, thus giving them better chance on succeeding.